# Concatenate two double arrays into a n x 1 cell array using matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, concatenation, cell

I have an `n x 1` double array.

```
A = [1234;
     1235;
     1236;
     1237;
     1238];
```

and a double Scalar.

```
B = [4567]
```

I want to combine (concatenate) these to make a `n x 1` cell array that looks like this,

```
C = [1234 4567;
     1235 4567;
     1236 4567;
     1237 4567;
     1238 4567];
```

Comment: C(:,1) = A;
C(:,2) = B;
C = num2str(C);
C = cellstr(C);

This works but seems like a super inefficient way to get there


Maybe it is the best solution though?

Comment: Do you want to convert the numbers to text, with a space between each element of A and the value of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one-liner:**

```
out = mat2cell([A,repmat(B,numel(A),1)],ones(numel(A),1),2)
```

**Sample run:**

```
A = [1234; 1235; 1236; 1237; 1238];
B = [4567];
```

**Results:**

```
out = 

[1x2 double]
[1x2 double]
[1x2 double]
[1x2 double]
[1x2 double]
```

If you want as `1xn` cells, you could just transpose the output

```
out = out.'      %//'

out = 

[1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]    [1x2 double]
```

Comment: I'd like it to be a 1 x n cell array so that I can use the ismember function to compare to another concatenated cell array of doubles. The doubles I have are datenumbers if that adds any context.

Comment: @AndyUngerman what would your `C` be if it was 1xn cell array? for the same problem

Comment: whos C
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  C         5x1             32900  cell

Comment: >> C

C = 

    '1234 4567'
    '1235 4567'
    '1236 4567'
    '1237 4567'
    '1238 4567'

Comment: @AndyUngerman Isn't that what you want? Mine gives the exact results